# How to implement async tasks in c#? Best practice

Tags: c#, async-await

I just learned some more about async await. I used to think everything in an async Task method just gets executed on a background thread. Now I understand that's not the case and went to refactor some of my code so its blocking less of my UIThread (WPF).

This is my "normal" async method:

```
public async Task<List<Data>> DoSomethingAsync(){
    var data = dbContext.Data.ToListAsync(); // <- Executes on a background thread internally
    ... // <- Executes on UIThread
    return dataList;
}
```

If I call that method in a ViewModel now, it will not actually be executed on a background. To do that I have to call `Task.Run(DoSomethingAsync);`.

I didnt want to just blindly wrap all my calls to async methods into Task.Run, so I found myself checking the implementation of every single method whether it has "..." content or is just wrapping an async method from ef core/http/filesystem.

What is the general idea here? Should all *my* async methods just look like this by default?

```
public Task<List<Data>> DoSomethingAsyncActuallyInBackground() {
    return Task.Run(() => {
        var data = dbContext.Data.ToListAsync();
        ... 
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

I feel like the first method is somehow "lying". It says Async, but calling it I have actually no idea whether it is truly asynchronous/non blocking code. Internally ef cores `ToListAsync()` works on a background thread right? Thats how its possible for it to be non blocking.

I am now realizing that I equate "asynchronous" with "on a background thread / non blocking". Is this even true?

Comment: `DoSomethingAsyncActuallyInBackground` is not a good idea . Let IO work be IO work, and if you have crazy cpu  bound work that is blocking the UI thread. Use `Task.Run` strategically.

Comment: You have some misconceptions about `async/await` and multithreading. You should consider reading [Tasks are (still) not threads and async is not parallel](https://www.wintellect.com/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/) and/or [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: _"Internally ef cores `ToListAsync()` works on a background thread right?"_ **No**. _"Thats how its possible for it to be non blocking"_ Again, no. See the two linked blog posts for detailed explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: Think about mailing a letter with certified mail.  You drop it in the mailbox without "creating an additional thread". Some time later, you get notified that the addressee received the letter - that's the nature of the post office "OS".  That's how async I/O operations work; you say "here do this, let me know when it's complete". The Task represents the work that is to be done. When you `await` a task, your program returns a Task that represents the Task you are awaiting *plus* the rest of the code in your method that hasn't run yet.

Comment: Take a look at these: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) and [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). TL;DR: *"Asynchronous methods should not be exposed purely for the purpose of offloading."*

Answer (score 2):

> I am now realizing that I equate "asynchronous" with "on a background thread / non blocking". Is this even true?

Asynchronous does mean "nonblocking", but "asynchronous" (in the modern sense of the word, as used by `async`/`await`) does *not* necessarily mean "on a background thread".

I recommend starting with my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and following up with [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). Consider the case of a database query: once the query is sent to the db server, there's no need for a thread to just sit there blocking, waiting for a response. Asynchronous code frees up that thread to do other things, and uses a `Task<T>` (a.k.a. "[promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)") to notify the application when the query results have arrived from the db server.

Comment: Is there such a thing as being "too async"?  Take for example the XmlWriter class with its WriteXXXAsync methods that would typically write out just a few bytes at a time. It would seem that the overhead of awaiting each individual call would greatly outweigh just a single await on an XElement.WriteToAsync for example.

Comment: Yes, there is such a thing as "too async". The "chatty" interfaces like that can cause performance problems if called at scale. `ValueTask` mitigates these performance problems, but methods that do very little I/O and also return `Task` can be problematic. I usually try to do formatting in-memory and then (asynchronously) write out the complete string all at once.

Comment: That's what I figured, and was very surprised to see those types of methods implemented in the XmlWriter class. Now I'm curious as to why they thought it necessary to include them.

Comment: @mford: I have seen multi-GB XML files that require streaming. Sad, but true.